# Access to client certificates and replacing certificate selection dialog in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there an extension API which allows to access client certificates? I would like to provide a modified certificate selector based on details of the certificate.

Additionally, as far as I understood, Google Chrome does not provide its own client manager but uses native solutions for client certificate management. Due to this, full certificate management may not be possible by design. But since Chrome allows to generate and import certificates generated by the html5  tag I was wondering if an extension could import client certificates.